# Куда стоит направить особое внимание при разработке с помощью javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Начав изучать JavaFX после Swing столкнулся с тем что у первого есть специальное ПО в виде Scene Builder.
Вместе с этим сразу возникли вопросы:

1. Стоит ли учиться писать java-код для GUI лишь прописывая его или
   создавать его в Scene Builder?
2. Если я стану создавать GUI в
   основном в билдере что я потеряю от этого, или наоборот приобрету?
3. И вообще насколько сложнее (или нет) станет процесс если буду пытаться
   создавать GUI без использования билдера?

Вопросы частично друг с другом перекликаются, но все же мне так проще было бы разобраться в выборе что возник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Стоит ли учиться писать java-код для GUI лишь прописывая его или
> создавать его в Scene Builder?

Как вам удобнее - так и делайте. Плюсы, которые я вижу в прописывании кода:

1. Если нужно будет в будущем поменять одно поле, то можно это сделать прямо в `fxml`, без загрузки `scene builder'a`
2. Вы более контролируете то, что и как у вас будет отображаться (если рассматривать тот же swing, как по мне, всякие генераторы слишком много непонятного кода генерируют)
3. `Scene builder` не все умеет делать. Например, вы можете в `fxml` прописывать константы из вашего кода, к которому `scene builder` не имеет доступа ( ну или это я не научился использовать константы в `scene builder'e`)

Пример.

Допустим, вы хотите использовать ваши константы в [Label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html). Константы хранятся в классе

```java
package my.so.example;

public final class MyConstants {
     public static final String RELOAD_LABEL = "Reload";
     ...
}
```

и чтобы вам это заиспользовать эти константы в `fxml`, нужно будет написать что-то подобное

```
<?import my.so.example.MyConstants?>

<GridPane fx:controller="my.so.example.Controller" ...
    <Label>
        <text><MyConstants fx:constant="RELOAD_LABEL"></text>
    </Label>
</GridPane>
```

и тогда `label` будет иметь значение из константы ( а не какое-то захардкоженное в `fxml`)

> Если я стану создавать GUI в основном в билдере что я потеряю от
> этого, или наоборот приобрету?

Смотри ответ выше.

> И вообще насколько сложнее (или нет) станет процесс если буду пытаться
> создавать GUI без использования билдера?

Все зависит от полученной сноровки. Если будете часто менять вручную fxml - то ничего не потеряете, а возможно (со всякими автокомплитами) будет даже быстрее.

Comment: Я так понял что самому прописывая все же получше будет, хотя и не критично. А в плане затрат времени на осваивание способов соотношение примерно такое же будет? Это конечно индивидуально все, но примерно оценить наверно можно?

Comment: все индивидуально. кому то может потребоваться год, кому то потребуется 2 дня

Comment: SceneBuilder удобен для начального прототипирования, когда сцену требуется минимально подправлять напильником, то проще уже руками в коде.